# Notepad++ tabbed and untabbed at the same time

Tags: windows-7, notepad++, tabs

I want Notepad++ to be tabbed (like it is by default) when I use the `Edit with Notepad++` context menu in explorer, but open in a new window without tabs (similar to Notepad/Notepad2) when I simply `Open` certain file extensions. If this could be done in a context menu item other than `Open`, that would be good too.

Notepad2 is good, but I would like the exact functionality of Notepad++ for untabbed windows (The way it highlights all instances of the selected word, keyboard shortcuts, etc.). Adding asNotepad.xml to the Notepad++ folder will make it open in a new window each time, but I want to be able to open tabbed windows at the same time.

Using `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" -multiInst -notabbar -nosession <text file>`  in cmd (which can easily be modified to put in a context menu, or possibly to work with "Open") will open Notepad++ in a new window without a tab bar. This seems good at first, but with this window still open, using `Edit with Notepad++` on any file will open it in this untabbed window.

Comment: Passing parameters to it worked? If so, you can edit the registry enter which is responsible for opening N++ when you click "Edit with N++". Here's how http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379120/notepad-right-click-to-open-file-in-a-new-window

Comment: That doesn't answer my question but thanks, that's useful to know.

Comment: You could try to install two different versions of N++ in two different locations and use that registry enter to open one of them and the double click to open a different version. That's just a workaround, though. You could set both versions to store config and personal files in the same folder so you don't lose data when moving form one window to another. Just make sure you uncheck "autoupdate".

Comment: This won't solve your problem, but as a workaround, you could always use the `Move to New Instance` option once it opens in the tabbed view.

Comment: @user117893 I downloaded the zipped version of Notepad++ 6.2.3 (while I have 6.3 installed). I opened a text file with the downloaded version: `notepad++.exe -multiInst -notabbar -nosession <text file>`, and then when I opened a different file with `Edit with Notepad++`, it opened within the same window. I hope it's obvious that having 2 files open in the same window with no tab bar isn't ideal! I had the same result when trying with several versions of Notepad++.

Comment: I investigated using the "Send to" facility in Windows to set up a tabbed and an untabbed shortcut. Put a shortcut to Notepad++ in the %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo folder
(This is usually in C:\Users\username>\Appdata\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo) adding the commandline flags as specified in the question. However, Notepad++ currently saves the settings when you specify -notabbar (even if you specify -nosession) so this kind of use does not currently appear to be possible without issues.

Comment: @Balthus Oh yeah, I didn't notice that. That part can be solved by downloading the zip version of Notepad++, and using that one for untabbed windows. But there's still the issue of trying to open an untabbed window followed by tabbed, and them both opening in the same window. I think I will have to hack the untabbed exe so that the process is unrecognisable to the regular install, but I have a feeling it won't be easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a trivial solution, so I've went with using 2 copies of Notepad++:

- (tabbed copy) Notepad++ 6.3 installation for opening files in tabs
- (untabbed copy) Notepad++ 6.3 compiled from source with a couple of hacky tweaks for opening files in new windows (untabbed).

Without the tweaks to the untabbed copy of Notepad++, files won't always open in the copy of Notepad++ that you would expect. I'm sorry if editing source files isn't suitable for superuser, but I hope this will be useful for somebody.

---

### Compiling the untabbed copy

The source code readme recommends compiling in Visual Studio 2005, but it compiled fine for me in Visual C++ 2010 Express (free from Microsoft - http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-2010-express).

Simply open npp.6.3.src\PowerEditor\visual.net\notepadPlus.vcproj (and convert the project if it asks you) and choose to build "Unicode Release". You can now test that it builds correctly:

[image]

This will place notepad++.exe in PowerEditor\bin, but you will need a copy of SciLexer.dll in the same directory before it will run. This comes with Notepad++, so simply download it from the site. Also create an empty text file "asNotepad.xml" in the same directory, which will make it untabbed and open files in new windows.

### Tweaks

In winmain.cpp, on line 214, change `"nppInstance"` to `"nppInstance2"`, or similar. With this changed, the tabbed copy of Notepad++ will not think that a Notepad++ window is already open when you only have untabbed windows open.

In Notepad_plus_Window.cpp, on line 32, change `"Notepad++"` to `"Notepad++2"` or similar. This is used in winmain.cpp on line 287. With this changed, the tabbed version will not include the untabbed windows when it is searching for currently open windows to open the file in.

Now build again, and move the PowerEditor\bin folder to wherever you like. If you wish the untabbed copy to open when you open certain file extensions (such as .txt), in Windows 7 I found that I had to rename "notepad++.exe" to "notepad++2.exe", otherwise it would open the installed (tabbed) copy.

---

Edit:

If you compiled from source and want the plugins menu, you also need to copy DLLs into the plugins folder from another copy of Notepad++.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use the "Send To" facility in Windows.

Put a shortcut to Notepad++ in the `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo` folder

(This is usually in `C:\Users\<username>\Appdata\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo`)

Right click on the shortcut, select properties and go to the shortcut tab.

Use `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" -multiInst -notabbar -nosession` in the Target field.

Now right-click on a file and Send To -> Notepad++ will open the file untabbed in Notepad++.

As the `-notabbar` flag currently seems to force Notepad++ to save it's settings, you should set up 2 shortcuts within SendTo:

One pointing at the standard installed version of Notepad++ called "Notepad++ Tabbed" (with the flags `-multiInst -nosession` appended to the end of the target field)

One (with `-multiInst -nosession -notabbar` appended to the target field) pointing at the zipped version of the program, called "Notepad++ Untabbed".

As long as both shortcuts have the `-multiInst` flag added, they can be run at the same time and you have FULL control over which version opens which document.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, Balthus, but with the tabbed Notepad++.exe opening with the `-multiInst` flag, files will open in a new window each time rather than in a new tab.